# mvc validate date/time is at least 1 minute in the future

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, validation

I am still getting my hands around MVC.

I have seen several similar questions, some custom code and various methods but I have not found something that works for me.

I have a search model that fills an HTML table with results inside of a partial view. I have this in my search results model:

```
public DateTime? BeginDateTime { get; set; }
```

Which is set to DateTime.Now in the controller. The user can specify that date and time to run a task with the search results' data on the model's POST call.

What I would like to do is validate that the date/time the user defined is at least 1 minute in the future. If this can be done as a client-side validation it will be better, but I am open to options as long as it works.

View:

```
Begin update: @Html.TextBoxFor(o => o.BeginDateTime, new { id="txtBegin" })
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 15):

Create a new Attribute:

```
public class FutureDateAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        return value != null && (DateTime)value > DateTime.Now;
    }
}
```

Now in your model set this attribute:

```
[FutureDate(ErrorMessage="Date should be in the future.")]
public DateTime Deadline { get; set; }
```

Comment: in the future you should show needed modules

Answer (score 0):

This is another good way to check that the date selected is from the future.

```
public class FutureDate : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        DateTime dateTime;
        var isValid = DateTime.TryParseExact(
        //Getting the value from the user.
        Convert.ToString(value),

        //We want the user to enter date in this format.
        "d mmm yyyy",

        //It checks if the culture is us-en
        CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,

        //Mosh has no idea what this does.
        DateTimeStyles.None,

        //Output parameter.
        out dateTime);

        return (isValid && dateTime > DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```